# Drupal Solr is indexing, but not showing any search results

Tags: drupal, solr, facet

I have a Drupal 7.17 installation running with Apache Solr installation (3.6.2) and Facets. The facets seem to work perfect, but when I navigate to the search page (with or without facets selected), no results are shown. Anybody an idea what could cause this?

Comment: In the mean time, I've found that it probably has something to do with the Facet API module: When I disable this module, and I navigate to the search page, I get to see the latest search results (I configured my Solr search page to show results if query is empty) and I can successfully use the search field. Once I enable the Facet API module (even with all actual facets disabled), i breaks again and no search results are shown on the search page. It looks like Facet API is altering the queries in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after hours of searching, I was finally able to fix the bug. If anybody bumps into the same problem, here it is: When using the facet api module in combination with Apache solr, you'll see the following options when creating facets under the Apache Solr settings in Drupal:

- show facet blocks on non-search pages (checkbox)
- show facets blocks on the following pages (textarea)

I had the checkbox enabled, and as I wanted to show the facet block on all pages, I entered * in the textarea. The problem however is (I guess), that facet block are then rendered twice on search pages (but you only get to see them once) and messing up the solr query, resulting in no search results.

So, obviously, what I did to solved this issue, was removing * from the textarea, and setting the paths where I wanted to display the facets (all, expect the search pages).